# How to fetch all select box value in one array list

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have generated dynamic select box in jsp and given names cb01,cb03..cb63 etc.
    Now i want to fetch these select box value in Action class variable like in ArrayList or in Map or in a array.
     Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide a few more details and maybe some code samples?

Comment: until multi-select, there will be only one selected value send back to your action class,moreover plz describe your question clearly.

Comment: Post your code. For multi-select boxes, the values transmitted by default is an array. Just inspect the HTML part of it and you can get understanding.

Comment: @Ben To be precise, the values transmitted are just a bunch of strings--there's no such thing as an array in HTTP. Any conversion of parameters into an array happens on the server side.

Comment: @Manish If the action property is a list, and you're using the correct name, this should happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Select Tag in JSP with `multiple="true"`

```
<s:select name="mylist" id="id_mylist" list="countryList" multiple="true"/>
```

On submit of the form calling the following Java Script. This will essentially mark all the element in the list as selected.

```
function doSubmit(){
 var mylistvar =document.getElementById("id_mylist");        
             if(mylistvar  !=null){      
                for(var x=0;x<mylistvar.options.length;x++){        
                    mylistvar.options[x].selected=true;
                }
             }

}
```

The ArrayList variable used above could looks like this.

```
private ArrayList<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This way when the form is submitted all the values in the list would be bind to the server directly as an arraylist.